# Accessing an ActionScript function via Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript, externalinterface, nomethoderror

I'm trying to call a function in an action script using the `ExternalInterface.addCallback` API, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Here's what I have:

ActionScript:

```
//MyClass.as  
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

    public class MyClass extends Sprite
    {
        public function MyClass()
        {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback('getStringJS', getStringAS);
        }

        public function getStringAS():String
        {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }
}
```

*NOTE: I'm compiling this into an swf using the flex mxmlc compiler if that matters.*

HTML/Javascript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User Identification</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <object id="MyClass" name="MyClass" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="MyClass.swf" width="1" height="1">
            <param name="movie" value="MyClass.swf">
            <embed src="MyClass.swf" width="1" height="1">
        </object>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var flash = document.getElementById("MyClass");
            var str = flash.getStringJS();
            alert(str);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'getStringJS'
```

I also tried adding in a timeout in case the swf file wasn't loading, but I didn't have any success with that method either.

Any thoughts?

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. The key way to signal the javascipt through `ExternalInterface.call` so we know for sure that the swf is loaded. The most "Universal" way to do this is as follows:

MyClass.as

```
//MyClass.as  
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

    public class MyClass extends Sprite
    {
        public function MyClass()
        {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback('getStringJS', getStringAS);
            if  (ExternalInterface.available) {
                ExternalInterface.call("isConnectedFlex");
            }
        }

        public function getStringAS():String
        {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User Identification</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <object id="MyClass" name="MyClass" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="MyClass.swf" width="1" height="1">
            <param name="movie" value="MyClass.swf">
            <embed src="MyClass.swf" width="1" height="1">
        </object>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var flash = document.getElementById("MyClass");

            function isConnectedFlex() {
                var str = flash.getStringJS();
                alert(str);
            }


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice example. Works still in 2017. For others, some other additional information can be found here as well: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb1.html

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is a matter of the flash not being loaded. I tried your code using the window.onload event and it worked for me:

The flash is the same...

HTML/JS :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User Identification</title>
    <head>
    <body>

        <object id="MyClass" name="MyClass" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="MyClass.swf" width="1" height="1">
            <param name="movie" value="MyClass.swf">
            <embed src="MyClass.swf" width="1" height="1">
        </object>

        <script>

            window.onload = function() {

                var flash = document.getElementById("MyClass");
                var test = flash.getStringJS("test");
                alert(test);   //pops up with "Hello World!" on Firefox

            };

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, it made me realize I really need to learn to check my work in other browsers haha. It works on Firefox and IE, but not chrome.  Either way I still need a more universally acceptable method. Any thoughts?

Comment: I see.  You might want to check out this link:  [problem-accessing-externalinterface-exposed-method-in-google-chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436722/problem-accessing-externalinterface-exposed-method-in-google-chrome)