# Flash analysis for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash

I'm reading a tutorial on how to create your own Chrome Extension using Javascript/HTML/CSS.
I wanted to practice a bit on a facebook flash game to make my life easier, you know what i mean BUT i don't know how to read flash memory online or how to analyse the content of a flash app online.

Do you know how could i do this ?

I read that we can interact with flash using Javascript so if it is possible i just need to catch methods, variables from flash to make my own Chrome Extension.

Regards, Jérémy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can interact with the Javascript in Flash using ActionScript [as an example can be found there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208561/accessing-an-actionscript-function-via-javascript) but it's only possible if the developer who developed the Flash app has integrated it voluntarily and publish which methods you can access (and how). You can guess that it's only a really rare case.

Outside of this specific case, you can't access anything outside of the information you can gather from the DOM elements embedding the Flash application.