# Multiple image uploader not working

Tags: php, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm attempting to create a multiple image uploader (think Coppermine) where the user clicks a button in an SWF, selects a file or multiple files, and then these files are uploaded to a directory.

I have a PHP script that handles the uploading a file, and my Flash file iterates over the files in the `FileReferenceList` and sends the file to this PHP script to upload. The directory path in the PHP script is correct, and permissions set to 777.

The contents of my ActionScript 3.0 class look like this:

```
package com.yourfightsite.imageupload {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.FileReferenceList;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class ImageUpload extends MovieClip {

        private var uploadURL:URLRequest;
        private var fileRef:FileReferenceList;

        public function ImageUpload():void {
            uploadURL = new URLRequest();
            uploadURL.url = stage.loaderInfo.parameters.uploadUrl;

            fileRef = new FileReferenceList();

            uploadButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
        }

        private function buttonClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
            var imageFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter('Images', '*.jpg');
            fileRef.browse(new Array(imageFilter));
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelectHandler);
        }

        private function fileSelectHandler(e:Event):void {
            for each(var fileToUpload:FileReference in fileRef.fileList) {
                addFileToQueue(fileToUpload.name);
                uploadSingleFile(fileToUpload);
            }
        }

        private function uploadSingleFile(file:FileReference):void {
            file.upload(uploadURL);
            file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        }

        private function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace('ioErrorHandler: ' + e);
            ExternalInterface.call('console.error', e);
        }

        private function progressHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {
            var fileRef:FileReference = FileReference(e.target);
            var percentUploaded:Number = Math.round((e.bytesLoaded/e.bytesTotal)*100);
            updateFileInQueue(e.target.name, percentUploaded);
        }

        private function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
            markFileInQueueAsComplete(e.target.name);
        }

        private function addFileToQueue(filename:String):void {
            ExternalInterface.call('addFileToQueue', filename);
        }

        private function updateFileInQueue(filename:String, percent:Number):void {
            ExternalInterface.call('updateFileInQueue', filename, percent);
        }

        private function markFileInQueueAsComplete(filename:String):void {
            ExternalInterface.call('markFileInQueueAsComplete', filename);
        }
    }
}
```

The three methods at the bottom of the class fire JavaScript functions in my HTML page that add the file names to a file queue widget, and update the percent value next to them, and finally mark them as complete.

However, when I select files, they are added to the file queue widget as expected and then nothing. The files aren't uploaded, the files in the file queue widget aren't updated, and no errors are thrown, either in the console (I'm using Chrome) or Flash when publishing my movie.

Can any one see any mistakes in my ActionScript above?

Comment: Does it do anything? Have you tried putting simple TRACE(" HERE(fn name)" ) in your actionscript to see which functions are firing and in what sequence? Also - why are you going Flash -> java script -> php? Why not skip the javascript?

Comment: I'm not a Flash programmer, my main proficiency is PHP, so the above class was put together via various websites and books as references/resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if these are mistakes, but here are some thoughts:

Is it possible to find out if `fileRef.browse()` is using the same object as the `file` object that does the uploading?

Add the event listener before starting the upload:

```
private function uploadSingleFile(file:FileReference):void {
    file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    file.upload(uploadURL);
}
```

And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436722/problem-accessing-externalinterface-exposed-method-in-google-chrome) may have some relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some actionscript to upload a single photo - adapt it for your needs. The PHP follows.

```
private function onUploadCompleteData ( event : DataEvent ) : void
{
    var resultXML : XML = new XML( event.data );
    if ( resultXML == null ) return;

    var storednameString : String = resultXML..filename[0];


}               

private function uploadPicture() : void
{
    uploadFileReference = new FileReference();
    uploadFileReference.addEventListener( Event.SELECT, onSelectFile, false, 0, true  );
    uploadFileReference.addEventListener( DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, onUploadCompleteData, false, 0, true  );
    uploadFileReference.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onUploadError, false, 0, true  );

    uploadFileReference.browse();

}

private function onUploadError( event : IOErrorEvent ) : void
{
     Alert.show( "Unable to upload picture.", "Photo" );
}       

private function onSelectFile( event : Event ) : void
{
    try
    {
        // this is where you pass stuff to PHP - file info, storage info
        var urlParams : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        urlParams.some_info = some_info;
        urlParams.sessionId = phpsessionId;


        uploadURL = new URLRequest();

        // this is where you'd put the URL for your server
        uploadURL.url = serverpathString + "/php/uploadPhoto.php";

        uploadURL.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        uploadURL.data = urlParams;

        uploadFileReference.upload( uploadURL );
    }
    catch ( error : Error )
{
        Alert.show( "Unable to upload file.", "Photo" );
    }               
}           


<mx:Form height="100%">     
     <mx:Button label="Select" click="uploadPicture()"/>        
</mx:Form>
```

PHP to upload a file:

```
<?php

  // there is a bug in the flex upload code where the session id isn't being sent. This is a patch for that.
  session_id( $_REQUEST[ 'sessionId' ] );
  $some_info = $_REQUEST[ 'some_info' ] );

  session_start();

  $maxSize = 1024 * 1000; // 1 Mb
  if ( $_FILES[ 'Filedata' ][ 'size' ] > $maxSize )
  {
          echo "<ret/>";
            return;
  }

  $filename_inbound = $_FILES[ 'Filedata' ][ 'tmp_name' ];

  $utc = microtime( true );

  move_uploaded_file( $filename_inbound, "/data/pictures/$filename" );

  // if you change the stored filename - here is where it gets returned to actionscript
  // return success / fail the same way
  echo "<ret><filename>$filename</filename></ret>";
?>
```