# JS callback that fires when JS exposed methods available on flash DOM object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, angularjs, swfobject

I have a flash object embedded into an Angular JS directive using the swf-object library. This is done in the link function. I am trying to develop a basic interface to the object via JavaScript so that I can change the position of some action-script Shape objects.  I want to grab the initial position coordinates from the flash object within the link function so that I can initially populate local scope variables and bind to the view.

```
app.directive("flashTest", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E", // add to a div
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: "flash/flash-test.html",
        link: function($scope, element) {
            /* Embed the swf */
            var
                flashVars= {},
                flashParams= {
                    allowScriptAccess: "always",
                    allowFullScreen: "true"
                },
                attributes= {};

            // embed
            swfobject.embedSWF(
                "/public/assets/flash/as-test/Main.swf",
                "flash",
                "550",
                "400",
                "11",
                "/public/assets/flash/expressInstall.swf",
                flashVars,
                flashParams,
                attributes
            )

            var
                $elResetButton = element.find("button"),
                flashDOMObject = document.getElementById("flash");

            // setup scoped variables
            $scope.j1x = flashDOMObject.j1x();
            $scope.j1y = flashDOMObject.j1y();
            $scope.j2x = flashDOMObject.j2x();
            $scope.j2y = flashDOMObject.j2y();
            $scope.j3x = flashDOMObject.j3x();
            $scope.j3y = flashDOMObject.j3y();

            // setup callbacks/watchers
            $scope.$watch("j1x", function() { flashDOMObject.setJ1x($scope.j1x) });

            $elResetButton.bind("click", reset);

            function reset() {
                flashDOMObject.reset();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

However, `flashDOMObject` does not have the exposed (via ExternalInterface) method `j1x()` when I try to invoke it. I've debugged this and the reason is the browser has yet to make the http request for the SWF file (and therefore doesn't know about the javascript exposed api). Is there anyway to register a callback for the compilation and **loading** of the assets of the directive template so that I may populate the scope variables once the swf file is loaded?

**UPDATE** Current working solution making use of a timed delay of 50ms after the swf file loaded before using the externally exposed functions on the DOM element:

```
.directive("junctions", function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: "E", // add to a div
            scope: true,
            templateUrl: "flash/flash-test.html",
            link: function($scope, element) {
                /* Embed the swf */
                var
                    flashVars= {},
                    flashParams= {
                        allowScriptAccess: "always",
                        allowFullScreen: "true"
                    },
                    attributes= {};

                // embed
                swfobject.embedSWF(
                    "/public/assets/flash/Junctions.swf",
                    "flash",
                    "550",
                    "400",
                    "11",
                    "/public/assets/flash/expressInstall.swf",
                    flashVars,
                    flashParams,
                    attributes,
                    function() {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            // setup scoped variables
                            $scope.j1x = flashDOMObject.j1x();
                            // setup callbacks/watchers
                            $scope.$watch("j1x", function() { flashDOMObject.setJ1x($scope.j1x) });
                        }, 50)
                    }
                )

                var
                    $elResetButton = element.find("button"),
                    flashDOMObject = document.getElementById("flash");

                $elResetButton.bind("click", reset);

                function reset() {
                    flashDOMObject.reset();
                    $scope.j1x = flashDOMObject.j1x();
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Is there a more dependable way of detecting when action-script methods exposed via the [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) api are available to use?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's not an Angular callback you need, but a callback from SWFObject once it's loaded. Looking at [its docs](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api), it does seem to provide a way of passing one.

```
swfobject.embedSWF(
  "/public/assets/flash/as-test/Main.swf",
  "flash",
  "550",
  "400",
  "11",
  "/public/assets/flash/expressInstall.swf",
  flashVars,
  flashParams,
  attributes,
  function() { 
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      // Do post-SWF-loading here
    });
  }
```

)

It's probably a good idea to wrap the callback in `$scope.$apply` to make sure that any scope variable changes are properly processed by Angular.

Comment: Angular gave me a "digest already in progress" error with this, so I put the code inside a $timeout so that it runs on the next digest. It still complained about the callbacks not being there! It seems the flash embed takes some time to register those functions on the DOM element. The only way I've got it working is to put 50ms of delay on the $timeout (a bit of a hack and unreliable, but hey ho).

Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be much documentation on this from Adobe.

Comment: I think this solution would do the job actually:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5294147/1030067

The directive is buried behind a wall of automated build code, and a Plunker would take an awful amount of time :/

I shall see if I can implement a decent solution based on the linked answer. Basically I want some indication angular-wide that the external interface is available.